# In IBM MQ (Java) how do I access all the queues under a given Queue Manager preferably using PCF?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, pcf

I am working with developing a platform for enabling a user for adding stubs to a repo. The stubs use IBM MQ for message queuing. I need to provide the facility to display all the queues under a given queue manager namely say "MQSQ16X0" so that the user gets to choose the queue.

I tried following this link - [Get ClusterName of MQ Queue using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922650/get-clustername-of-mq-queue-using-java)
but this wasn't of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Admin REST API -

`GET /ibmmq/rest/v1/admin/qmgr/{qmgrName}/queue`

> Retrieves details of all queues that are defined in the named queue
>   manager, optionally specifying which queue attributes are retrieved.

Unfortunately you need a MQ server to access the swagger page. Its easier if you create an instance in the cloud. Then the url for the swagger page will be

`https://host:port/ibm/api/explorer`

There is a tutorial that guides you through using the REST API - https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/ibm-mq-messaging-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

I have made many posts about MQ, Java & PCF on StackOverflow.  I'm surprised you didn't find this one:  [Is it possible to get only the queue names of local and alias queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200789/is-it-possible-to-get-only-the-queue-names-of-local-and-alias-queues/17218608#17218608)

Also, I often write/post MQ, Java & PCF sample code on my blog at: [Roger's blog](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/) - click on either the Java or PCF category.